# ifstream.rdbuf behaves in an unexpected way

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream

I used following code to read a sample text file and read it in to a string.with this i have tried several different approaches to do the same and all gave me the same result. the  intention was to read the file as it is . as i have examined the final string contains data with spaces.

Actual file contains    =   harshana

the resulting string    =   h a r s h a n a

std::ifstream inFile(fileName,std::fstream::binary);

```
if (!inFile.is_open()) return NULL;

stringstream stream;
stream << inFile.rdbuf();

string str = stream.str();

char *buf = new char[str.length()];
str.copy(buf, str.length());
```

Comment: You are probably using some character encoding (utf-16?). You can open the file in hex editor to confirm that.

Comment: how do i do that please help

Comment: I do not know what OS you are using. Just find some simple hex editor and use it open the file. If you will see `68 00 61 00 72 00 73 00 68 00 61 00 6E 00 61 00 h.a.r.s.h.a.n.a` it would mean that you are using `utf-16`. You can either change the encoding in the text editor (ascii, utf-8) or use third party library to handle utf-16 `http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html`.

Comment: Replace all of the ifstreams and strings with `wifstream`s and `wstring`s. It looks like the original file is in little endian... if you have windows that could be likely. Open your file in notepad++ and look at encoding... or try other software that will tell you the file's encoding.

Comment: You realize `buf` is not null-terminated?